# Endless scrolling and filtering JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I've been using [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net) recently to display my JSON data in a table. I use it because it has a search bar and I can filter the data really easily and it had pagination (showing links to Page 1, 2, 3, etc)

I'm in need for an alternative solution of listing data that allows me to filter (search bar that matches text to data) and have an infinite scroll. More specifically, scrolling the body or a div container (not a scroll inside the table).

I don't necessarily need a "table" but just need to be able to style a box for each piece of data. If anyone has any solutions, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: why not extend datatables so that scrolling to the bottom loads the next page?

Comment: @dandavis I don't want to load the next page, it needs to append to the bottom. And I've been searching for hours and can't find a method.

Comment: ahh, good point. you can change the # of rows shown instead of next page, then on the old bottom row, call scrollIntoView()

Answer (score 0):

@dandavis helped with the idea

```
var tableNumRows = 15, activeForms = $('#the_table').dataTable();

$('#pageContent').bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
        var oSettings = activeForms.fnSettings();
        tableNumRows+=15;
        oSettings._iDisplayLength = tableNumRows;
        activeForms.fnDraw();
    }
});
```